# Switch stylesheets in an Ember CLI application

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm creating an application using Ember CLI. The user should have the option to switch the theme.

There are two Less files (`theme-one.less` and `theme-two.less`), one for every theme.

I'm looking for the Ember-way to conditionally load either the 'theme one' or 'theme two' file. Is there an Ember-way, or should I manually update the `href` attribute of the CSS `<link>` element?

Comment: More general questition: Is there anyway to use a property (from a service) in `index.html`?

Answer (score 1):

FYI, there is a switch stylesheet ember-cli that you can use:
[https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-theme-changer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-theme-changer/)

---

#### Install Theme Changer

```
ember install ember-theme-changer
```

#### Modify the code below in ember-cli-build.js:

```
// ember-cli-build.js
    outputPaths: {
      app: {
        css: {
          'light': '/assets/light.css', // FOR LIGHT THEME => app.scss
          'dark': '/assets/dark.css' // FOR DAR THEME => dark.scss
        }
      }
    },
```

#### Create your own SCSS with difference configuration.

1. Go to app/styles folder
2. Create dark.css and app.scss

dark.scss

```
body{
 background-color: black;
}
```

app.scss

```
body{
 background-color: light;
}
```

#### All you need just to make two button to switch the css file that you apply to

Think of it this easy way:

### In Html template application.hbs

```
<link href="light.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >

<button class='light'>LIGHT MODE</button>
<button class='dark'>DARK MODE</button>
```

### In Javascript File

```
$('.light').click(function (){
   $('link[href="light.css"]').attr('href','black.css');
});
$('.black').click(function (){
   $('link[href="black.css"]').attr('href','light.css');
});
```

comments: You can use other addon (more complicated) which it can be found on:

1. https://www.emberaddons.com/
2. [https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-themed-syntax](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-themed-syntax/)

Answer (score 0):

For what I know there isn't any way to modify `index.html`, but I've followed this post on how to apply a theme to my application:

https://medium.com/@jonpitch/ember-theming-97e9562084c7#.mfugkic8r

It uses sass but I've applied the same concept on less.
Basically, you should create a service in which you define a `theme` property that you use as a `data-theme` attribute in your templates and a modifier in the `less` style
(it's easier to read the post than explaining)